# How to suppress Hazelcast MC logging

Tags: hazelcast

We get log entries from Hazelcast like this over and over in Tomcat's catalina.out:

```
2023-03-19 15:36:17,376 [ INFO] [DisabledLoginCleanupThread] [c.h.w.s.s.i.DisableLoginStrategy]: Starting scheduled disabled login cleanup.
2023-03-19 15:36:17,376 [ INFO] [DisabledLoginCleanupThread] [c.h.w.s.s.i.DisableLoginStrategy]: Finished scheduled disabled login cleanup.
2023-03-19 15:36:17,942 [ INFO] [MetricsStorageDiagnostics] [c.h.w.s.m.MetricsStorageDiagnosticsLogger]: 

Known time series: 138,514
Tracked minute buckets: 35,312
Number of persistence runs: 360
Total persistence run time: 00:00:11.060
Max persistence run time: 00:00:00.399
Average persistence run time: 00:00:00.030
Last hour average persistence run time: 00:00:00.030
Total persisted minute buckets: 2,110,910
Max persisted minute buckets per run: 35,312
Average persisted minute buckets per run: 5,863
Last hour average persisted minute buckets per run: 5,863
Total dropped data points that arrived when the target minute bucket is no longer tracked, but not yet released(persisted) : 0
Total evicted dangling minute series : 0
Persistent store TTL: 24:00:00
Persistent store size on disk: 538.4 MiB
Data point memory compression ratio: 41.65
```

From the documentation, it seems this should suppress those entries but it doesn't:

```
System.setProperty("hazelcast.mc.log.level", "ERROR");
```

We have tried everything we can think of to no avail.  Anyone know how to suppress those?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, even though the above line of code works on all our other servers, one server required that the property be defined in tomcat8.conf instead:

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dhazelcast.mc.log.level=ERROR"
```